# Errors - what could they mean? Also is there another way to pull data besides the example code?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to pull data from api cart but I am not experienced with API or PHP - it would be my still-first-time experience to try working on API. I am wondering what the errors mean. Also I would like to know if it is possible to do it in a simple way so it could apply to html page to display image only? CURL is enabled on server.

ERRORS example

```
Error 1Auth failed.
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /var/www/images/test.php on line 17

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: 1 in /var/www/images/test.php on line 17

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: ^ in /var/www/images/test.php on line 17

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /var/www/images/test.php:17 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/images/test.php(17): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('1') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/images/test.php on line 17
```

PHP Examples

```
 <?php
    $shop='www.shop.com/content/admin/plugins/api/index.php?';
    $user = "dsp";
    $password = "ds127";
    $token = 'token';

    // Assemble the account url
    $url = 'https://'.$shop."username=".$user."&amp;password=".$password."&amp;token=".$token. "&apiType=xml&call=GetProducts";

    // Setup the cURL object
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

    $response=curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $image_xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
  foreach($image_xml->ThumbnailImageUrl as $thumbs){
echo "<img src=".$thumbs."/>";
}

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
curl_setopt($l_oCurl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

To

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

Comment: The XML errors mean you didn't receive XML.  var_dump() the string returned by curl.  It's probably an error message.  However, fixing the curl issue Unsigned identified might very well cause curl to return valid XML, resolving the additional errors.